# Extend material-ui component using forwardRef and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have the following javascript code, [here is the full implementation](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react/blob/master/src/components/CustomButtons/Button.js).

```
    import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

    const RegularButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
      return (
        <Button {...rest} ref={ref} className={btnClasses}>
          {children}
        </Button>
      );
     }
```

How do I extent a material-ui component with typescript?

Comment: By changing the file's extension to `.tsx`

Comment: sorry, I mean with the correct props types. Something like that

``` const RegularButton = React.forwardRef(
  (props: IRegularButtonProps, ref: any) => 
```

Comment: Here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151411/343900

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible answer [here](https://github.com/Umapreethi-G/material-kit-react/blob/8c1624d4f4652bf8ae9a48372afd72c2923afc81/src/components/CustomButtons/Button.tsx)

```
interface IRegularButtonProps extends WithStyles<typeof buttonStyle> {
  color?: string;
  round?: boolean;
  ...
}

const RegularButton = React.forwardRef(
  (props: IRegularButtonProps, ref: any) => {
 ...
}
```

Basically it extend the default buttons props to create an overloaded props.
I do not know if it is the correct way of do it, but was the best solution that I found.