# Why does React.createRef() for material-ui Button element in TypeScript not work correctly?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Using React v16.13.1 I have the following component class with a Material-UI Button component and a RefObject to access the button element.

```
class Search extends React.Component<any, any>{

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)

    this.streetViewRef = React.createRef();
  }

  private streetViewRef: React.RefObject<Button>;
}
```

for the following Button element

```
<Button ref={this.streetViewRef} size="sm" variant="primary" block >Street View</Button>
```

However, the following TypeScript error is displayed.

[image]

What needs to be changed to correct this error?

Comment: looks like it may use `forwardRef` so the ref type is `React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>` but I'm not sure, that error message is not very clear, otherwise you probably wouldn't need to ask :)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look here https://www.selbekk.io/blog/2020/05/forwarding-refs-in-typescript/

The correct way to type a forwardRef component is:

```
type Props = {};
const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, Props>(
  (props, ref) => <button ref={ref} {...props} />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create ref with HTMLDivElement.

```
createRef<HTMLDivElement>()
```

So, this would be better.

```
private streetViewRef = createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
```

Comment: Using HTMLDivElement results in the same TypeScript error. Also seems like the RefObject should be typed to match the HTML element which is a Material UI button?